# vertica copy command with based on the content of the csv

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to run copy command that populate the db based on concatination of the csv.

db columns names are:

```
col1,col2,col3
```

csv content is (just the numbers, names are the db column names):

```
1234,5678,5436
```

what i need is a way to insert data say like this:
based on my example:

i want to put in the db:

```
col1, col2, col3
1234, 5678  "1234_XX_5678"
```

should i use FILLERS?
if so what is the command?

my starting point is:

```
COPY SAMPLE.MYTABLE (col1,col2,col3) 
FROM LOCAL 
'c:\\1\\test.CSV' 
UNCOMPRESSED DELIMITER ',' NULL AS 'NULL' ESCAPE AS '\' RECORD TERMINATOR '
' ENCLOSED BY '"' DIRECT STREAM NAME 'Identifier_0' EXCEPTIONS 'c:\\1\\test.exceptions' 
REJECTED DATA 'c:\\1\\test.rejections' ABORT ON ERROR NO COMMIT;
```

can you help how to load those columns (basically col3)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There different ways to do this.

**1 - Pipe the data into vsql and do the data edit on the fly using linux**

**Eg:**

```
cat file.csv |sed 's/,/ , /g' | awk {'print $1 $2 $3 $4 $1"_XX_"$3'} 
|vsql -U user -w passwd  -d dbname -c "COPY tbl FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',';"
```

**2 - Use Fillers**

```
    copy tbl(
v1 filler int ,
v2 filler int ,
v3 filler int,
col1 as v1,
col2 as v2,
col3 as v1||'_XX_'||v2) from '/tmp/file.csv' delimiter ',' direct;

    dbadmin=> select * from tbl;
 col1  | col2  |     col3
------+------+--------------
 1234 | 5678 | 1234_XX_5678
(1 row)
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to make the two input columns - which you load as-is anyway - FILLERs. This will do:

```
COPY mytable (
  col1
, col2  
, col3f FILLER int
, col3 AS col1::CHAR(4)||'_XX_'||col2::CHAR(4)
)
FROM LOCAL 'foo.txt'
DELIMITER ','
```